# How can I upload Camera app photos to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, ipad

On an iPad Air 2, is there a way to upload videos that I took with the iPad's Camera app to the iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

Apple says:

On your iOS 8 device

```
In the Photos app, tap Shared at the bottom of the screen, then tap Sharing at the top of the screen.

Tap the shared album you want to add to, then tap the Add button .

Find photos or videos to add.

For example, tap Photos, Shared, or Albums to find photos.

Tap the photos and videos you want to add, then tap Done.
```

<sub>source: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12070?locale=en_US</sub>